# can I set Active Record callbacks for arbitrary model methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Can I set Active Record callbacks for arbitrary model methods? I can see how this would be useful, similar to before_filter in the controller.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking if these callbacks even exist? Because yes! they do! Here is a list of them for you! http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: No I'm asking if I can set callbacks for methods other than the traditional :save, :create, etc. For example, I might like to have before/after callbacks for the purchase.submit method...

Comment: Well if you own the method (i.e you implement it yourself) then you can just stick your code in there. Otherwise, you may want to look up Ruby Aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Model Callbacks provides an interface for any class to have Active Record like callbacks. You can check it out here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html

And this works for any arbitrary method in your model. Here is a code snippet.

```
class MyModel
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  define_model_callbacks :initialize, :only => :after

  after_initialize :update_info

  def initialize
    run_callbacks :initialize do
      # Your create action methods here
    end
  end

  def update_info
    puts 'info'
  end
end
```

This will call the "update_info" method after finishing "initialize" method.